# Find consecutive duplicate values in a multi dimensional array in Lua

Tags: multidimensional-array, lua, lua-table

```
data = {{1,2,3},{1,2,1},{1,2,3},{1,2,1},{1,2,3},{1,2,1}}
qty = 1 -- dynamic variables

function find_sequence(qty)
    if qty < 1 or qty > #data then
        print("INVALID INPUT or NOT ENOUGH DATA")
        return
    end

    local results = {}
    for i = 1, #data - qty + 1 do
        local sequence = {}
        for j = i, i + qty - 1 do
            table.insert(sequence, table.concat(data[j]))
        end
        local key = table.concat(sequence, " ")
        if not results[key] then
            results[key] = 1
        else
            results[key] = results[key] + 1
        end
    end

    local count = 0
    for sequence, occurrences in pairs(results) do
        if occurrences >= 2 then
            count = count + 1
            print("FOUND:", sequence:gsub("%d", "%1 "), "Occurs:", occurrences, "times")
        end
    end

    if count == 0 then
        print("NOT FOUND")
    end
end

find_sequence(qty)
```

The script is working when qty = 0, qty = 1, qty = 2, qty = 3, qty = 5, qty = 6 and qty `>` #data.

But it gives wrong output when qty = 4:

```
FOUND: 123 121 123 121, Occurs: 2 times
```

The expected output should be `NOT FOUND`, as there is no duplicate of 4 consecutive values in the table.

Comment: Please clarify what the problem statement is. Do you want to find a consecutive sequence of `qty` duplicate values? Currently you're counting how often (overlapping) subsequences of length `qty` occur. Are you trying to determine whether there are duplicate subsequences of length `qty`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what your script does:

- It rejects invalid inputs (`qty < 1 or qty > #data`)
- Then it stringifies all subsequences of length `qty` and uses them as keys into a table to count their occurrences. There are two maybe-issues with this:

  - `table.concat(data[j])` uses no separator. You can't distinguish `11, 2` and `1, 12` that way. If your values are guaranteed to be single digits, this is fine, although it raises the question of why you aren't using strings right away.
  - The subsequences are *overlapping*.
- Finally, you check whether any subsequence appeared twice or more times. Again, a subsequence and an overlapping subsequence will be considered a duplicate.

What happens when `qty = 4` is that you do indeed have two overlapping subsequences with the same contents:

- The first 4 items: `{1,2,3},{1,2,1},{1,2,3},{1,2,1}`
- The last 4 items: `{1,2,3},{1,2,1},{1,2,3},{1,2,1}`
- The middle 2 items are the overlap

In string form, both of these are `123 121 123 121`, which is what you're seeing. Since that is not what you want, I assume that the goal of your code is to find *disjoint* duplicate subsequences.

One simple approach to achieve this would be to just remember *where* the first and the last subsequence was to only count non-overlapping subsequences. Change

```lua
if not results[key] then
    results[key] = 1
else
    results[key] = results[key] + 1
end
```

to

```
if results[key] then
    results[key].max = i
else
    results[key] = {min = i, max = i}
end
```

This gives you a range. If the indices are at least `qty` apart, at least two subsequences don't overlap. Thus you can change your check in the loop from `if occurrences >= 2 then` to `if occurrences.max - occurrences.min >= qty then`. You could even avoid this second loop altogether and directly perform this check when a duplicate subsequence is encountered.

For counting duplicate subsequences, you'll first have to define how to count them.